# How TO Delete Large Amount Of rows in online table informix Db

Tags: informix

I Have a large Online Table (13 Million Rows Per Day) , I Want Move Yesterday Rows to Another Table And DELETE From Online Table .

I've tested a method :

1 - Select 100000 Rows By Rowid From top of table and insert to another Temp table .  (Estiated Time : 0.87s)

2 - insert Selected Rows To Second Table By Temp Table Map . (Estiated Time : 1m12.59s)

3 - Delete Selected Rows From First (Online) Table By Temp Table Map  (Estiated Time : 5m39.38s -> it's Too Long  Help Me Please ). 
informix 12.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your queries with `SET EXPLAIN ON` enabled and confirm that the optimizer is performing the slow step the way you presume. If it is not, you may need to apply optimizer directives or adjust your index strategy. (Bear in mind the more indexes, the more pages that need to be modified.)

If the `INSERT` and then `DELETE` operations are taking too long, is it feasible to use expression based fragmentation? This would give you the option to `DETACH` yesterday's fragment, and attach it to the off-line table.